# How can I include default js and css scripts in dynamically added CakePHP element?

Tags: jquery, cakephp-3.x

I have a form where the user can dynamically add additional rows using jquery and a CakePHP element to create multiple records from the single form.

The first field on each row is a select control.  The select control has 'selectpicker' class and attribute to make the select options searchable.  This works based on an implementation of bootstrap and a 'bootstrap-select' plugin, both of which (js and css) are loaded in my default.cpt layout.  This works perfectly.

[image: https://i.imgur.com/ooEEIXN.jpg]

The code for the select control looks like this:

```
    <?= $this->Form->control("fruits.0.fruit_id", ['options' => ['Apples','Oranges','Bananas', 'Tomatoes'], 'empty' => '-- Select Fruit --', 'label' => false, 'id' => 'fruit'.0, 'class'=>'selectpicker', 'data-live-search' => 'true']); ?>
```

In `\src\Template\Element` I created an Element Fruits.ctp with this form row.  I can call this element directly to add an additional row and it works perfectly:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/NGfkgAs.jpg]

However, I want the user to be able to add form rows dynamically as needed.  To achieve this I have implemented the following:

1. The table footer has a link to add a row.

```
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td class="actions">
                        <a href="#" class="add">Add Fruit</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

2. Just after the fieldset is this script:

```
    <script id="fruit-template" type="text/x-underscore-template">
        <?php echo $this->element('fruits');?>
    </script>
```

3. At the end of the form page is this script:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    var
        fruitTable = $('#fruit-table'),
        fruitBody = fruitTable.find('tbody'),
        fruitTemplate = _.template($('#fruit-template').remove().text()),
        numberRows = fruitTable.find('tbody > tr').length;

    fruitTable
        //ADD AN ENTRY LINE    
        .on('click', 'a.add', function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

            $(fruitTemplate({key: numberRows++}))
                .hide()
                .appendTo(fruitBody)
                .fadeIn('fast');
        })

        //REMOVE A ENTRY LINE
        .on('click', 'a.remove', function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        $(this)
                .closest('tr')
                .fadeOut('fast', function() {
            });    
        });
    if (numberRows === 0) {
        fruitTable.find('a.add').click();
        }
    });
</script>
```

This setup works well using the Element template like this (Fruits.ctp):

```
<?php
$key = isset($key) ? $key : '<%= key %>';
?>

<tr>
    <td>
    <?= $this->Form->control("fruits.{$key}.fruit_id", ['options' => ['Apples','Oranges','Bananas', 'Tomatoes'], 'empty' => '-- Select Fruit --', 'label' => false, "id" => "fruit{$key}", 'data-live-search' => 'true']); ?>
    </td>
    <td>
        <?= $this->Form->control("fruits.{$key}.quantity", ['label'=>false]); ?>
    </td>       

    <td class="actions">
        <?php
        if($key == 0) { echo '<a href="#" class="remove">Remove Fruit</a>'; }
        ?>

    </td>
</tr>
```

Notice in the template, I do NOT define the `'class'=>'selectpicker'` on the select control.  This works and produces a form row with a "standard" select control (no bootstrap-selectpicker formatting and function):

[image: https://i.imgur.com/RxJlHNa.jpg]

If in the template I set the select control class to selectpicker:

```
<?= $this->Form->control("fruits.{$key}.fruit_id", ['options' => ['Apples','Oranges','Bananas', 'Tomatoes'], 'empty' => '-- Select Fruit --', 'label' => false, "id" => "fruit{$key}", 'class'=>'selectpicker', data-live-search' => 'true']); ?>
```

Then the row is added, but the select control disappears:
[image: https://i.imgur.com/CXS8ee9.jpg]

If I inspect the element of the empty table cell where the select control should be, I can see the control there, but it is invisible and does not have all the containing divs that the bootstrap select-picker normally has.

So my question is, how can I call the bootstrap-select (and other bootstrap) js and css so that it is applied to the new element, even though the page is already loaded and the element is being added "inline"?

Thanks in advance for any advice or guidance.
D.

Comment: Try creating a custom selector with css. Reference url: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_custom_select.asp

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the solution was much simpler than I thought.

In my script to add the new element with the select control, I can call bootstrap-select in the link on click via:

```
        $('select').selectpicker({
        liveSearch: true
        });
```

And that's it.

It still doesn't really answer my question but the problem in this context is solved for now.  I'll reframe my question and post with jquery tags if needed.